# Counting number of sets with the given restriction.

Tags: combinatorics

I want to count the number of sets (empty/non-empty) formed with n natural numbers if it is given some pairs of numbers can't occur together in a set. What is the fastest way to do this if I am considering large n upto 1000 . I want a quick algo for a computer program.

Comment: Is it possible that some of the pairs might share elements?  For example, could the set of given pairs include both $\langle1,2\rangle$ and $\langle2,3\rangle$, so that 2 can't share a set with either 1 or 3, but 1 and 3 can be in the same set?

Answer (score 1):

The total number of subsets is $2^n$. The number of **bad** subsets, where specific numbers $a$ and $b$ both occur, is $2^{n-2}$. This is because the bad subsets are the sets made up of $a$, $b$, and *any* subset of the rest of the numbers.

Thus the number of good subsets is $2^n-2^{n-2}$.

**Edit** In a comment, it is asked how one can count if several pairs are to be not allowed. One can do it by using the above method, and Inclusion/Exclusion, if the number of not allowed pairs is quite small. That quickly gets out of control if a medium-sized set of pairs is to be excluded.

Comment: Nicolas: I forgot to specify that there can be many pairs like that. for example (1,2) (2,3) (4,5) must not occur together in any set if numbers can be chosen from 1-5 inclusive for making a set.